# how to delete a blob in .jsp

Tags: java, jsp, google-app-engine

I am trying to delete an image blob from my app through my .jsp file, so far I've got this:

```
<%
blobString=key.getProperty("keys").toString(); //vale "keys" is the blob-key from datastore, the above code loops through all my pictures and gets the key for all of them
BlobKey blobKey = new BlobKey(blobString);
%>

    <form action="<%=blobstoreService.delete(blobKey)%>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="submit" value="delete" name="delete"> 
    </form>
```

I cant get it to work and I am a beginner in this area, can anyone spot what Im droing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a handler on your server, for example, `/delete`, where you would process delete requests when a user submits such a request.

```
<form action="/delete" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="submit" value="<% blobString %>" name="delete">
```

You cannot set an Object like BlobKey as a value in your HTML code. It only accepts a string.

This code goes inside your `/delete` handler:

```
blobstoreService.delete(new BlobKey(blobString));
```

Note that to create a blobString you need to call

```
String blobString = key.getKeyString();
```

method, not `.toString()` that you are trying to use.